# Return full array if one row within the array contains a given value R

Tags: r

I have nested data that looks like this:

```
ID  Date Behavior
1   1    FALSE
1   2    TRUE
1   3    TRUE
2   1    TRUE
2   2    FALSE
3   1    TRUE
3   2    TRUE
```

I'd like to return each array of values for a given ID that contains at least one occurrence of `FALSE`. I am expecting ID 1 and ID 2 to be returned, with each row of present data (3 rows for ID 1 and 2 rows for ID2).

EDIT: here is what I am expecting:

```
ID  Date Behavior
1   1    FALSE
1   2    TRUE
1   3    TRUE
2   1    TRUE
2   2    FALSE
```

I'm wondering if this is a `for` loop or a `while` function - any and all help is appreciated...

Extra points for python code that mimics the R code!

Comment: What's the desired output for your example?

Comment: Just updated that - actually before I realized you commented..

Comment: I'm still unclear on the structure of the output that you desire. Is it just a data.frame missing the last two rows?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, sorry for being unclear - that's exactly what I'm after, but of course, I have a much larger data set and would like to iterate over all of the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table` approach (assuming `df` is your data set)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(!Behavior)], ID] # you can also replace any(!Behavior) with !all(Behavior)
#    ID Date Behavior
# 1:  1    1    FALSE
# 2:  1    2     TRUE
# 3:  1    3     TRUE
# 4:  2    1     TRUE
# 5:  2    2    FALSE
```

Edit: a bit more efficient solution by @Arun

```
setDT(df)[, if (any(!Behavior)) .SD, ID]
```

---

Or a similar `dplyr` approach

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(!Behavior))

# Source: local data table [5 x 3]
# Groups: ID
# 
#   ID Date Behavior
# 1  1    1    FALSE
# 2  1    2     TRUE
# 3  1    3     TRUE
# 4  2    1     TRUE
# 5  2    2    FALSE
```

Comment: Can you provide some logic for the data.table function?

Comment: When you do `!` before a logical vector, you are converting all `FALSE` to `TRUE` and the opposite. Thus, if you have atleast one `FALSE` in a certain `ID` it will be converted to `TRUE`. This is where `any` steps in. If there atleast one `TRUE` accurance per `ID` `.SD` will select the whole thing because we are running it per `ID`

Comment: I'd make a slight modification: `DT[, if (any(!Behaviour)) .SD, by=ID]` - this doesn't have to run `[.data.table` for each group - therefore will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here's using base R (assuming your data is in a data.frame named `dd`)

```
dd[with(dd, ave(!Behavior, ID, FUN=any)), ]
```

Comment: We were interestingly thinking almost the same...

Comment: And i thought I was being tricky with `any` and negation. I guess i'm not as clever as I thought ;) Nice.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, wondering what the ave does and FUN command...

Comment: `FUN=` is just the name of a parameter in `ave()`. If you see a function you are not familar with in a solution, i suggest you start by reading the help page for that function. Try reading `?ave` and exploring the documentation and the examples.